# Trying to get token back from localhost redirect URI in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

Now, before we start, I know I'm not following best practices here, but I've had trouble getting that implemented, and I just need this to work for a demo.

I am trying to do either implicit or hybrid login, preferably with the OIDC JS Client library (preferably, though not necessarily the React wrapper).

I've installed inappbrowser, and I am trying to connect it with userManager.signinRedirect().

I'm managing to get the tokens back at my redirect URI (http://localhost), but I can't seem to save them for whatever reason.

I've got this executing on button click:

```
userManager.signinRedirect();
```

And ideally I'd love to tie this to the userManager signinRedirection window open.

```
    ref.addEventListener( "loaderror", function(event){
      var loop = window.setInterval(function(){
          ref.executeScript({
                  code: "window.shouldClose"
              },
              function(values){
                alert(event.url);
                if(event.url.includes("#session_state")) {
                    ref.close();
                    window.clearInterval(loop);
                  }
              }
          );
      },100);
  });
```

How am I supposed to do this?

I just want to launch an inappbrowser window to my auth endpoint (or identity provider therein), and then capture the return which will look like this, and which my application is currently registering, but not processing:

```
http://localhost/#state=15b40137c71f437cb2fc256e7d1aa82f&session_state=c719b57d-357a-4752-a92a-5155aa1eb365&id_token=eyJhbGciO....&access_token=eyJhbGc......
```

How do I save these values?

Is there anyway to contact inappbrowser with this endpoint and pass the data back to my program?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the inAppBrowser ? You're already in a webview?? Just do this in your webview and save your data in localStorage

Comment: Because you need to do OIDC authentication this way

Comment: The information is only passed to a redirect URI.

Comment: No my friends, read this https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html